# Angular textarea not binding when dynamically added

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm trying to add answers to question dynamically by clicking the Add Option button.
Here is my code:

**From the html file**

```
<span (click)="addQuestionOption()" style="cursor: pointer">Add Option</span>

<div *ngFor="let itineraryQuestionOption of itineraryQuestion.ItineraryQuestionOptions; index as idx" [hidden]="questionIsTextType">
    <textarea name="answer" [(ngModel)]="itineraryQuestion.ItineraryQuestionOptions[idx].answer" rows="2" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>
```

**From code file:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.itineraryQuestion = {};
    this.itineraryQuestion.ItineraryQuestionOptions = [];
}

addQuestionOption() {
    this.itineraryQuestion.ItineraryQuestionOptions.push({
        answer: ''
    });
}
```

Here is what is happening:

Click Add Option, it adds a new textarea. Enter value in it.

Now click Add Option again, a new text area is added but the value in previous textarea is gone.

This happens whenever I click Add Option.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide a  stackblitz ?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I copy-paste your code and it is working for me.. idk how to help you then

Comment: That is strange :(

Comment: Maybe if you publish more code of both .ts and .html files I could help you to find it